# Increasing RAM size on Ubuntu 16.04 running in VMware Workstation

Tags: vmware, ram

I'm running a Windows 10 64-bit host OS on a Dell XPS 9560 with 8GB of RAM.

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 for programming purposes using VM Workstation, and currently allocated 1GB RAM for the Ubuntu 16.04 guest OS. From what I noticed now the VM's performance is a little slow from time to time, especially when starting an app (Like CLion IDE or Firefox for example).

I need a performance boost, so is there a way to increase the RAM size in the existing Ubuntu 16.04 guest OS, rather than having to install a whole new guest OS in VMware Workstation and allocate more RAM during the installation process?

Comment: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1004059

Answer (score 4):

Allocate enough virtual hardware resources in the VMware settings for the existing Ubuntu guest OS. This will change only the VMware settings for the existing Ubuntu guest OS without changing anything else in the guest OS itself.

- 2 CPUs instead of 1 CPU
- at least 2GB of base memory (recommend 4GB for your Dell XPS 9560)
- at least 25GB virtual hard drive
- more graphics memory than the bare minimum amount

[image]